# How can I send emails after a method call with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

I am trying to send emails with the Meteor email package, but am having trouble getting it to work.  I can't call the email from the client because the email can't get sent until certain attributes are in the database.

Here is my current code:

```
var dataContext = {
    numParticipants: numParticipants,
    link1: link1,
    link2: link2
}
var email = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.paidEmail, dataContext);
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    this.unblock();
    Email.send({
        to: sendTo,
        from: 'example@email.com',
        subject: 'Your creation has been created!',
        html: email
    });
}
```

I am unsure how to move forward with this. I get a `Template is not defined` error in this case, and if I wrap the beginning part within a `Meteor.isClient`, it does not pass to the second portion.

Any ideas?

Comment: I for one don't understand where your code exists, and what context it is called under

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Clearly state your requirement. You want to send an email after calling a server side method right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a little confused about the way Meteor works isomorphically.  Whilst you can use the same code block on both client and server, it will be in completely different instances, so you can't just render some HTML using the client-side Blaze library and expect it to be available on the server in the following block, just because they're in the same file before your app was built; they will exist in completely different contexts when your app is actually running.

You need to wrap the server code in a [`Meteor.methods`](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) block and call this from the client. Something like:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    var dataContext = {
        numParticipants: numParticipants,
        link1: link1,
        link2: link2
    }
    var email = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.paidEmail, dataContext);
    Meteor.call('send-email', sendTo, email);
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        'send-email': function(sendTo, email) {
            this.unblock();
            Email.send({
                to: sendTo,
                from: 'example@email.com',
                subject: 'Your creation has been created!',
                html: email
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

**Two notes:**

1. Once you're at this level of complexity, it's highly advisable to start breaking your code-base down into separate client and server files (in the [appropriate directories](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)).  As this example demonstrates, you *can* put both in the same file, but there's no real advantage if your code-base isn't tiny, and it rapidly gets confusing.
2. It can be quite beneficial to use `Futures` for slow async calls in server methods like `Email.send`.  I haven't put it into the example above as it would only cloud the issue at this stage, but it's definitely worth [looking in to](https://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828399), particularly for methods that need to provide feedback.

Comment: I tried your method to send mail but it is still taking same amount of time as it takes without unblock. What could be the issue?